# Clustering in Jahia community mode

Tags: cluster-computing, jahia

Can we do clustering in Jahia community edition? without using any tools which come with enterprise version?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's easily possible to enable clustering in the community version of Jahia. Of course, since the source is GPL, nobody will prevent you for adding it if you want to do it but it's properly not going to be a easy task.

Why not buy the enterprise edition, it's not 'that' expensive if you are a company and help Jahia grow a better CMS?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do cluster with community edition, and that's not a new thing for Jahia.

If you want to see the difference between community and entreprise distributions of Jahia, read "Distributions Comparison Table" on  [Jahia's developers "get started" page](https://www.jahia.com/get-started/for-developers#product-download).

Comment: And what about clustering tomcat under Jahia ?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that clustering in community is not possible. and will not. I worked with jahia in enterprise. a little late, but for all which will search for that.